# The orthogonal projection of $\gamma(x)=2e^{2\pi xi}$ over the subspace generated by ...

Tags: functional-analysis

The orthogonal projection of an element $x_0 \epsilon$ H over a convex set C is the element $y_0 \epsilon$ C such that $\|x_0-y_0\|=\min_{y \in C}\|x_0-y\|$. Find the orthogonal projection of $\gamma(x)=2e^{2\pi xi}$ over the subspace of $L^2(0,1)$ generated by $f(x)=x$.

Can someone tell me what the procedure of to find the orthogonal projection?

Comment: If your convex set is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space, then the map that sends an element to its orthogonal projection is a rather nice bounded linear operator, isn't it? And in the case that your closed subspace is just the span of a single non-zero vector, that rather nice bounded linear operator has a *very* explicit form, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection of $e^{2\pi i x}$ onto the subspace $M=\{ \lambda x : \lambda \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is the unique $\lambda x$ such that
$$
                (e^{2\pi i x} - \lambda x) \perp M
$$
Equivalently, you must find $\lambda$ such that
$$
                \int_{0}^{1}(e^{2\pi ix}-\lambda x)x\,dx =0.
$$